# eplain TeX footnote spacing

Tags: footnotes, plain-tex, eplain

I've been experimenting with the features provided by eplain and for the most part, I quite like them. I'm confused about one thing though. I don't seem to be able to adjust the inter-line space in the foonote section at the bottom of a page, when using eplain's footnotes.

For example:

```
\input eplain
\everyfootnote={\sevenrm}

This is some text. It contains a footnote\numberedfootnote{Nothing really to say.}.
This is yet more text. It contains another 
 footnote\numberedfootnote{Still nothing to say.}.
This is even more text. It contains a final 
 footnote\numberedfootnote{Why is the footnote spacing so ugly?}.

\bye
```

Produces this at the bottom of the page:

[image: output of above code]

How can I change the spacing between the footnotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With executing `\sevenrm` you don't change the baselineskip (and the footnote number's size).

Load `fontch.tex`, which supports `\eightpoint`; no `\sevenpoint`, though.

```
\input eplain
\input fontch
\everyfootnote={\eightpoint}

\vsize=3cm % just for the example

This is some text. It contains a footnote\numberedfootnote{Nothing really to say.}.
This is yet more text. It contains another
 footnote\numberedfootnote{Still nothing to say.}.
This is even more text. It contains a final
 footnote\numberedfootnote{Why is the footnote spacing so ugly?}.

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I tried also adding a `\sevenpoint` macro, but the result is really poor: footnotes should be two point less than the main size, not more.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\input eplain
\everyfootnote={\sevenrm}
\interfootnoteskip = 1in

This is some text. It contains a footnote\numberedfootnote{Nothing really to say.}.
This is yet more text. It contains another 
 footnote\numberedfootnote{Still nothing to say.}.
This is even more text. It contains a final 
 footnote\numberedfootnote{Why is the footnote spacing so ugly?}.

\bye
```